# Where can I find the algorithm for processing the "weights (parameters)" of the tree for implementing the bonus system?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm

It is necessary to develop a system of motivation to attract customers to the site in order to increase the turnover of money.

So, it was decided to use referral links, those from a certain person (person K) have a link, he gives it to friends / acquaintances (person N), they also enter this referral link (person K) when registering an order and receive their own referral link , Which can already be given to other people ..

When a person (person N) pays and receives his order, which was issued using a referral link, then (person K) receives a certain percentage from this order ...

And so on down the tree: if (man K) leads his people (man X) and when they make the order, the bonuses get everything up the tree (K -> X) ...

I need to find an algorithm (description or name) that would allow it to be done, I'll implement it in PHP.

BUT as it is necessary to calculate the expediency and percentage of the bonus in general ...
For example: I'm ready to spend 10.000 bonuses on bonuses (so that X person gets 10,000), so I want to know what percentage for each level of attracted to be put and how many levels there can be and how many nodes, so that the root of the tree will earn 10,000 bonuses, well, N, I want to play and the total number of bonuses, levels, nodes ... to estimate the real situation, perhaps there is some online service that allows you to do this?

Thankful in advance for any help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqCil.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Each node/object/person can have a parent field where you point to whom the referral originated.

You can create a recursive function to increase the bonuses of each parent, until there are no more parents. When 5 makes a purchase, you can check whether or not 5 was referred aka whether or not 5 has a parent. If yes, apply bonus to parent (2), and then check if the parent (2) was referred by someone. Repeat this step until the check for parent returns false.

```
function bonus($N) {
  if ($N->parent === 0) { //The base case is: no parent.
     return 1;
  }
  else {
     //I didn't understand how you plan to apply bonuses, so
     //you can input here as you see fit.
     //apply bonus to $N->parent

     //This is the recursive step.
     return bonus($N->parent); // Check if the parent has a parent.
  }
}
```